# Is it possible to take input multiple images and upload to server in php?

Tags: php

I am using this to select multiple images in HTML.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

how can I upload these images to the server in php?

Comment: and does the path is exists in your live server ?

Comment: Not possible in PHP

Comment: Of course that is not possible. The user either has to upload the files to your server; or you have to do this on the client-side, using JavaScript.

Comment: The PHP code runs on the server, not on the client computers. It runs for you because you use a single computer as server and client but this doesn't usually happen (except when you develop the code).

Comment: _“how can we do that in JavaScript ?”_ – do some research ... https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+read+local+file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities/answers to your question:

- Server-side files: YES, it's possible, only if the webserver (apache, nginx, ...) have access rights to the folder. Any language can do this: also Javascript, with NodeJS.
- Client-side files: NO, it's impossible. It can be a security breach because it means that anyone can make an application to access your local files.

Comment: It is not "according to me" , it's according to all web bowser "security policies", that's all.